# Transpose sql query result - Posgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot, lateral-join

I've a below result set.

```
Id Name Age
1  abc  3
```

Required Result:

```
Id 1
Name abc
Age 3
```

Comment: You can't do that in SQL (because a directly transposed resultset cannot be meaningfully represented in SQL: SQL only supports resultsets of identically-typed tuples, but a transposed ordered set of typed tuples cannot be represented by another set of tuples (with their own corresponding same-type) because each output row (tuple) will need its own types (e.g. your 2nd row's value is `'abc'` but the others are `int` values. Anyway, the human-readable display of a resultset is a _presentation layer_ concern, so you should implement transposition in your PHP/cshtml/report-generator tool instead.

Comment: Thanks @dai, I could able to achieve using other way. Thought, there might be a way to do it using SQL.

Comment: Some SQL implementations (like SQL Server) support `PIVOT`/`UNPIVOT` - and Postgres has `crosstab` ([which isn't enabled by default](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html)) - but in both cases they only support tranformations of tables such that all output rows use the same output columns (name and type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *unpivot* in a lateral join - but as mentionned by Dai in the comments, this requires casting all values to the same datatype. So:

```
select x.*
from mytable t
cross join lateral ( values
    ( 'Id',   id::text ),
    ( 'Name', name     ),
    ( 'Age',  age::text)
) x(col, val)
```